# @gorhom-react-native-bottom-sheet | How to add a clickable custom backdrop to the bottom sheet

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I am using https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet to add a bottom sheet.
I need to add a [custom backdrop](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/custom-backdrop/) to the bottom-sheet , I am able to add it as below :

```
const CustomBackdrop = ({animatedIndex, style, onPress}) => {
  // animated variables
  const containerAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    opacity: interpolate(
      animatedIndex.value,
      [1, 0],
      [0.5, 0],
      Extrapolate.CLAMP,
    ),
  }));

  // styles
  const containerStyle = useMemo(
    () => [
      style,
      {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      },
      containerAnimatedStyle,
    ],
    [style, containerAnimatedStyle],
  );

  return (
    <AnimatedPressable onPress={() => onPress(0)} style={containerStyle} />
  );
};

   <BottomSheetModal
  backdropComponent={(props) => (
    <CustomBackdrop {...props} onPress={handleSheetChanges} />
  )}
>
  ...
</BottomSheetModal>;
```

But now the issue is that if above backdrop is added, it does not allow the click events under the sheet as mentioned [here](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/397)

I also tried adding another way of adding backdrop :

```
 <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      {isExpanded && (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleSheetChanges(0)}>
          <View style={[styles.backDrop]} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      )}
 
      <BottomSheetModal> ...
```

But with this approach, backdrop is visible only when bottom sheet has snapped to a point ( updating `isExpanded` on [onChange](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#onchange) event ) , is there a way where I can get the event as soon as drag of action sheet has started so that backdrop is visible as the bottom sheet is pulled up ?

Many Thanks.